# Authentication issue in CSS in dnn

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

I am working on dnn site and facing some issue related with authentication.

When i'm going to browse a url ../admin/ControlPanel/module.css, it's showing 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

I have verified all the settings in IIS, still not able to understand why this error is coming.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the only file/path that is having that problem?

I would start by checking to see if you have Basic Authentication enabled in IIS.

Make sure there isn't a virtual directory or application configured on the admin folder for some odd reason.

Comment: Admin folder is not accessible. I have tried to create one txt file in the admin folder that is also not accessible.There is only anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS. Is there any settings in dnn CMS itself for admin folder permission?

Comment: Finally the issue gets solved. The issue is that we need to enable anonymous authentication for admin folder. That's why we are unable to see any files in that folder due to authentication.

Comment: I honestly have never had to enabled that on a folder basis in IIS before.